# How to group data in highcharts when zoomed out

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

This is the highchart option I am using:

```js
let min = moment(new Date(1549011531000)).startOf("day").unix() * 1000
let max = moment(new Date(1549011531000)).endOf('day').unix() * 1000
let reportCount = [{"x":1549011531000,"title":"5","text":null},{"x":1549011547000,"title":"10","text":null},{"x":1549011559000,"title":"1","text":null},{"x":1549011577000,"title":"5","text":null},{"x":1549011588000,"title":"5","text":null},{"x":1549011658000,"title":"0","text":null},{"x":1549011682513,"title":"1","text":null},{"x":1549011695000,"title":"2","text":null},{"x":1549011709000,"title":"3","text":null},{"x":1549011726000,"title":"4","text":null},{"x":1549011743000,"title":"5","text":null},{"x":1549011756000,"title":"6","text":null},{"x":1549011769000,"title":"7","text":null},{"x":1549011779000,"title":"8","text":null},{"x":1549011791000,"title":"9","text":null},{"x":1549011802000,"title":"10","text":null}];
let reportLine = [{"x":1549011531000,"y":5},{"x":1549011547000,"y":10},{"x":1549011559000,"y":1},{"x":1549011577000,"y":5},{"x":1549011588000,"y":5},{"x":1549011658000,"y":0},{"x":1549011682513,"y":1},{"x":1549011695000,"y":2},{"x":1549011709000,"y":3},{"x":1549011726000,"y":4},{"x":1549011743000,"y":5},{"x":1549011756000,"y":6},{"x":1549011769000,"y":7},{"x":1549011779000,"y":8},{"x":1549011791000,"y":9},{"x":1549011802000,"y":10}];
let options = {
      tooltip : {
        hideDelay: 0,
      },
      plotOptions : {
        
        series : {
          turboThreshold: 100000,
          pointStart : min,
          pointInterval : 60 * 60 * 1000
          
        }
      },
      chart: {
        height : 180,
        alignTicks: false,
        panning: false,
        zoomType: 'x',
        resetZoomButton: {
          position: {
            align: 'right',
          },
          theme: {
            fill: 'white',
            stroke: 'silver',
            opacity: 0.8,
            r: 0,
            states: {
              hover: {
                fill: '#41739D ',
                style: {
                  color: 'white'
                  
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        animation: false
      },
      xAxis: {
        tickLength : 0,
        min : min,
        max : max,
        type : 'datetime',
        tickInterval : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        ordinal: false
      },
      rangeSelector:{
        enabled: false
      },
      navigator: {
        enabled: false
      },
      scrollbar:{
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        adjustChartSize: true,
      },
yAxis : [{
        opposite: false,
        className: "YPR",
        min : 0,
        max : 15,
        tickInterval : 3,
        id: "PR",
        labels: {
          align: 'left',
          x: -6
        },
        title: {
          text: "Reports Graph",
          style: {
            color: '#0082af',
          },
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
      }],
      series: [
        {
          name: "Reports Series",
          data: reportLine,
          id: 'PRLINE',
          yAxis: "PR",
          type: 'line',
          color: 'transparent',
          enableMouseTracking: true,
          zoneAxis: 'y',
        },
        {
          name: "Report",
          type: 'flags',
          data: reportCount,
          shape: 'circle',
          id: 'PR',
          yAxis: "PR",
          style: { // text style
              color: 'white',
              fontFamily: 'Manrope',
          },
          color : '#2c618a',
          fillColor : '#2c618a',
          width: 15,
          height : 15,
          allowOverlapX : true,
          onSeries : 'PRLINE',
          enableMouseTracking: true,
          zoneAxis: 'y',
          states: {
            hover: {
                color : '#2c618a',
                fillColor: '#2c618a', // darker
                lineWidth : 5,
                lineColor : '#2c618a',
            }
          },
          lineColor : '#2c618a',
          lineWidth : 5,
          // y : 10
        }
      ]
    };
    Highcharts.stockChart('report',options)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highstock/6.0.3/highstock-all.js"></script>
<div id="report" class="chart" style=" width: 100%"></div>
```

Since there is a lot of data in that very minute, the flags are clubbed together and not visible quite clearly.

How can I sum up all the data and show it as a single flag when other flags are nearby and the chart is completely in a zoomed out state (1 day is maximum zoomed out state), and when the chart is zoomed in and it is possible to show all the flags then it should display all the flags on respective position.

Comment: Have a look at [dataGrouping](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.line.dataGrouping) in the API, it can probably serve your purpose

Comment: can you show an example in answer @ewolden ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by setting appropriate `dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth`. Check the demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataGrouping: {
        groupPixelWidth: 100
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lr4c3612/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth

Comment: doesn't work as expected, need to group data and sum them when data overlaps

Comment: You can make it using `dataGrouping.approximation = "sum"`. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/158qxgwf/1/. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.approximation